# mcrypt_encrypt on string containing ":" (colon)

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, encryption, mcrypt

My web application gets URL objects from clients, encrypts it using `mcrypt_encrypt` , and stores the result in a MySQL DB as type LONGTEXT. This entire thing is done as shown below:

```
    /* $copied below is received from user and can be any string. But I'm just using a URL as example,as that's where it fails */
    $copied = "http://www.google.com"
    $encCopied = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,$encryption_key,$copied,MCRYPT_MODE_CFB);

    $copystuff = "UPDATE LinkTable set copied='$encCopied'";

    mysqli_query($db,$copystuff)
```

When this code is executed, the MYSQL query on the last line fails with a "syntax error". After a lot of hours of debugging, which involved manually changing the `$copied` variable in the above php, I finally figured out that it happens because of the colon (":") in `$copied` variable. When I change `$copied` to `www.google.com` , no SQL syntax error is thrown, everything works perfect. But, if I then change `$copied` to `:www.google.com` , SQL again gives syntax error.

Note that this code works for every other type of string, but fails only when a colon is present. My assumption is that `mcrypt_encrypt` encrypts the colon into some unworkable thing that MYSQL is not able to process.

The error displayed is like this,when there is a colon present:
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'wcÀeHÿë%†‚;/æ1ÎíëO¤SÌ­ÎúR²#•Wwðg   T¥4ª¨\£%@‚y' at line 1**

Any inputs on why this could be happening? Right now, I'm making the application work by sending the URL after stripping of the `http://` part from the URL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure somewhere in there is a character that is borking the SQL. Try escaping your encrypted string:

```
$copystuff = "UPDATE LinkTable set copied='" . mysqli_real_escape_string($encCopied) . "'";
```